# MVC Ajax array post method doesn't work

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My problem is that when I post data with ajax  with code below

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("ChangeOrder", "Menu")',
                        data: JSON.stringify(array),
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                            if (data.Status == 200) {
                                toastr.success('@Resources.Resource.Success_MenuOrderSave');

                            }
                            else {
                                toastr.error('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                                return;
                            }
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        beforeSend: function () {

                        },
                        complete: function () {

                        }
                    });
```

It occurs error when send array that has 227 item in it, but it work if array has 10 items , Is there a limit for this ?

```
 var item = {
                            refMenu: data[i].id,
                            refParent: null,
                            refPortal: "@SessionRepository.GetPortalId()",
                            Order:i+1
                        }
```

array of item is above. 
Error is 500 it acts as get method when array is big. but it works when array is not big

Error is

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The JSON request
>   was too large to be deserialized.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you updated your web.config to allow more than 64k in a request? The defaults are small to stop sites being overloaded.

Comment: 500 means internal server error so it is the code processing it that is throwing an error.  debug your controller

Comment: 500 is a server side error check your code there may be some case

Comment: it is not going to controller.

Comment: in web config  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" /> i added this

Comment: Enable error reporting in your web.config so you get full error details (and not just error 500)

Answer (score 0):

Try a bigger value for aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers in the web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a higher max JSON value for aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers in the appSettings:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000000" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: So the *first* of two identical answers gets down-voted out of the blue... Gotta love the inhabitants of this realm.